# Stripping all vowels but the first from a set of strings

Tags: bash, shell, string, regular-expression

I have a string comprised of multiple substrings, separated by underscores. For example: `AbcdAEfd_hEgdgE_AbAAAAA`. I need to remove all vowels except the first from each substring. So:

- `AbcdAEfd` -> `Abcdfd`
- `hEgdgE` -> `hEgdg`
- `AbAAAAA` -> `Ab`

The resulting string should be `Abcdfd_hEgdg_Ab`

Answer (score 4):

Pure bash solution, using just parameter substitution:

```
#! /bin/bash
suffix=${1#*[aeiou]}
prefix=${1%$suffix}
vowel=${prefix: -1}
prefix=${prefix%?}                  # Remove the vowel from the prefix
suffix=${suffix//[aeiou]/}          # Remove the vowels.
echo "$1 -> $prefix$vowel$suffix."
```

Comment: What's the point of removing the `$vowel` from the prefix only to add it back at the end?  Am I missing something?

Comment: @jw013: If you only want to print it, there's probably no point. For testing, though, it is useful :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `perl`'s [zero-width look-behind](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) regex syntax.

```
perl -pe "s/(?<=[aeiou])([^aeiou_]*)[aeiou]([^aeiou_]*)/\1\2/ig"
```

This next snippet treats an input line as a single string (not multiple sub-strings).

```
perl -pe "s/(?<=[aeiou])([^aeiou]*)[aeiou]/\1/ig"
```

Comment: hi peter this one is working fine but the thing is _ must be the delimter for the second occurence of the vowel not the entire word

Comment: You had better give clear examples as an update to your question (not in the comments, as they usually don't show things as clearly) ... It is a bit confusing when you say it works fine, and it produces the output stated in your question, and you now mention a delimiter.. I just don't know what you mean by that (I can only guess).

Comment: iam sorry i got confused...let me give a clear example ABCDAEFD_EHGDGE_ABAAAAA in this word the output should be ABCDFD_EHGDGE_AB . again iam sorry i should have given correct example

Comment: Peter.O  i guess this is clear?

Comment: @anonymous: you should put the specs in your question. That way everyone coming to the page will see what you want. Here only the people who can be bothered enough to read the comments will see it... Re; what you've just presented, it still seems(?) to be wrong?  why does the second *word* have a trailing E?  I *think* what you are asking for is to leave only the first vowel in any `_` delimited word.. (but I don't know for sure)... In any case. *put the specs in your question* (just prefix it with the word UPDATE: or something like that)...

Comment: ok i will definitely follow these things next time UPDATE:Yes you are right it is like leave only the first vowel in any _ delimited word

Comment: @anonymous `ABCDAEFD_EHGDGE_ABAAAAA` → `ABCDFD_EHGDGE_AB`, really? Why is the second `E` retained?

Comment: UPDATE:oh god iam wrong again is should be ABCDFD_EHGDG_ABFrom the left of the table name, remove vowels from each word in the table name except for the first vowel of each word.

Answer (score 0):

Does python count? This should work:

```
cat anonymous.txt | python -c "import sys; x=sys.stdin.read(); print(x[0]+''.join([z for z in x[1:] if z not in 'AEIOUaeiou']))"
```

I tried with tee and named pipes as well, but it kinda failed:

```
makefifo pipe; cat anonymous.txt | tee >(cut -b1 >> pipe&) >(cut -b1- | tr -d aeiouAEIOU >> pipe&) > /dev/null; cat pipe | xargs -d '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/^/\n/;ta;:a;s/\n$//;t;s/\n\([^aeiou_]*[aeiou]\)/\1\n/i;:b;s/\n\([^aeiou_]*\)[aeiou]/\1\n/i;tb;s/\n\([^aeiou]*\)/\1\n/i;ta' file
```